# How can I make a dropdown menu open with a keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im using a bootstrap example of a dropdown menu. It opens and closes just how it should with a mouse click. I'm wondering how can I configure this code to mimic the same functionality when using the keyboard?

I don't want to create a new custom control. By hitting "tab" I can move from one focusable element to another.

**What I've tried:**
I've attached the role="button" attribute, as well as a tabindex=0. When I hit tab until i get to the dropdown menu icon (chevron-down), It opens up the menu when I hit the spacebar. However I cant close the dropdown menu, rather it stays open. Can anyone share any ideas on how to open and close this menu?

```
<div class="appExperience small-tile">
<div class="blue-bar">
    <h2 class="tile-header">APPLICATION EXPERIENCE</h2>
    <span class="dropdown hidden-xs">
        <i class="tcm-chevron glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down expand-icon dropdown-toggle"
           role="button"
           aria-labledby="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"
           ng-src="{{dropdown_appExperience}}"
           data-toggle="dropdown"
           tabindex="0"
           alt="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"></i>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu appExperience tileContextMenu">
            <li>
           List Item 1
            </li>
            <li>
           List Item 2
            </li>
             ...
```

Comment: Probably not your answer, but pressing ESC will close the dropdown menu. [Tried on the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you can trigger a click event from JavaScript. If you're familiar with jQuery, you can do for instance:

```
$(window).on("keydown", function(){ $(".dropdown").trigger("click") });
```